# MySQL - Workbench (PHP): Linking data in multiple tables WITHOUT JOIN query command

Tags: php, mysql, mysql-workbench

MySQL - Workbench (PHP):

Is it possible to link multiple tables in a relational database without using the JOIN, or INNER JOIN query commands, without duplicating data in tables?

For instance I have two tables with collumns:

1. TUsers (Related to TCompanies,1-n)

   - ID_TUsers (UNIQUE ID)
   - TUsers_UserName
   - TUSers_UserContactNumber
2. TCompanies

   - ID_TCompanies (UNIQUE ID)
   - TCompanies_CompanyName
   - TCompanies_CompanyContactNumber

In essence; I want to access COMPANY data from the USERS table without doing a JOIN query between the two tables...

Comment: Yes it's possible, but *why* do you need this? Which column is your foreign key?

Comment: For efficiency, the database is a lot bigger than this example. If it were to be possible to create this functionality in workbench, it will reduce the amount of PHP coding that will be done. Sorry I forgot to mention the TUsers_CompanyID field in the TUsers table (foreign key).

Comment: Why do you think that a JOIN will be less efficient than the answer you accepted?

Comment: Beacuse it doesn't have the word JOIN in it lol.  In all seriousness though, you should use queries as and when you need them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends what you are trying to do, you can use a where clause but you don't seem to have any fields which indicate a join between the two tables.  Is there a foreign key in either of the two tables?

Since you now mention you have a `TUsers_CompanyID` in the `TUsers` table you can do the following:

```
SELECT TUsers.TUsers_UserName, TCompanies.TCompanies_CompanyName FROM TUsers, TCompanies WHERE TUsers.TUsers_CompanyID = TCompanies.ID_TCompanies;
```

Comment: Basically, the User creates a profile (with his personal details), and is required to be registered as a company, thus all the user information contains his/her personal details and company details.. I forgot to mention the TUsers_CompanyID field in the TUsers table (foreign key)

Comment: Ive edited my comment, I don;t see any reason not to use a where clause or a join wherever they are necessary.  It doesn't bulk up PHP really and the queries are there for a reason.

Comment: This is a Join actually. Not explicit but still a join, in the old, really old, ANSI-89 syntax.

Comment: Ah fair enough :), either way theres no reason for them not to use queries like this when they are needed, since that is what they are there for.